# Probability question: don't agree with solutions

Tags: probability

All humanities students at a university study either History or English. Every year, the university chooses two of the humanities students at random to receive a scholarship. There are 140 History students at the university. The probability that the two humanities students chosen for the scholarship are a specific English student and a specific History student is 1/9800.

How many English students are at the university?

The answer says:

The correct answer is 70 English students. As the probability that the university chooses a specific English student (E) and a specific History student (H) for the scholarship is 1/9800:

$$\frac{1}{E} \times \frac{1}{H} = \frac{1}{9800}$$

$$E \times H = 9800$$

$$E = \frac{9800}{H}= \frac{9800}{140} = 70$$

This doesn't really make sense to me..
Here's how I approached the question

Let $x$ be the total number of students

$$ P = \frac{1}{x} \times \frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{x} \times \frac{1}{x-1} = \frac{2}{x(x-1)} = \frac{1}{9800} $$

Alternatively

$$ P = \frac{1}{^xC_2} = \frac{1}{\frac{x(x-1)}{2}} = \frac{2}{x(x-1)} = \frac{1}{9800} $$

But not only is this different to the solutions, but you also get a non integer $x$. But I still don't agree with the solutions.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is the solutions wrong?

Thanks..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem failed to specify that the selection process is "one English student is chosen at random, and one History student is chosen at random." Only under this modification does the given solution makes sense.

Your approach would be correct if the selection process was a random selection of two students, as the problem statement incorrectly implies.

Comment: Well, something is incorrect. Assuming the answer is correct and the problem isn’t is a bit of a leap.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Usually when the problem statement says one thing and the supposed "solution" say something else, I would just say the "solution" is answering a different question than the one asked. But in this case the problem has no good answer: if there is exactly one English student the probability is $1/9870$, and any other number of English students gives an even smaller probability. So I really don't think it's that much of a leap to conclude that the problem statement asked the wrong question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If the problem statement is correct, then OP and David K have pointed out that there is no sensible answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let there be $N$ English students at the university. The probability that a specific History and a specific English student are selected is $1/N \times 1/140 = 1/9800$, which gives $N=70$

Comment: That assumes two English students or two history students can’t receive the scholarships, which the problem definitely does not state.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews But the problem is only computing the probability of one student from each discipline getting the 2 scholarships. It does not make an assumption one way or another about both scholarship recipients being from the same discipline (and it's not really needed to solve the problem). Could just be a case of a very simple but not very well stated problem.